# JavaScript - How to create Table from the Object?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner with JavaScript, I need little help. I want to take the user input and make a student object. The last step is to print the object into a table.
The object is successfully created, however, I'm not sure how can I insert the object details (`id`, `name`, `surname`, `points`, `didpass`) into the table.
Any help is appreciated!

```js
//-------------//
// Form Layout //
//-------------//

// h1
let headerText = document.createElement('h1');
headerText.id = 'topH1'
headerText.innerText = 'Please fill the empty fields'

// Student Id - Label
let studentId_lbl = document.createElement('LABEL');
studentId_lbl.classList.add('label1');
studentId_lbl.innerText = 'Student ID';
// Student Id - Field
let studentId = document.createElement('input');
studentId.id = 'studentIdEntry';
studentId.classList.add('field')
studentId.name = 'studentIdEntry';
studentId.type = 'text';
studentId.placeholder = 'Enter your ID ';

let EmptyRow = document.createElement('br');


// Student Name - Label
let studentName_lbl = document.createElement('LABEL');
studentName_lbl.classList.add('label2');
studentName_lbl.innerText = 'Student Name';
// Student Name - Field
let studentName = document.createElement('input');
studentName.id = 'studentNameEntry';
studentName.classList.add('field');
studentName.name = 'studentNameEntry';
studentName.type = 'text';
studentName.placeholder = 'Enter your Name';

// Empty Row
let EmptyRow2 = document.createElement('br');

// Student Surname - Label
let studentSurname_lbl = document.createElement('LABEL');
studentSurname_lbl.classList.add('label3');
studentSurname_lbl.innerText = 'Student Surname';
// Student Surname - Field
let studentSurname = document.createElement('input');
studentSurname.id = 'studentSurnameEntry';
studentSurname.classList.add('field');
studentSurname.name = 'studentSurnameEntry';
studentSurname.type = 'text';
studentSurname.placeholder = 'Enter your Surname';

// Empty Row
let EmptyRow3 = document.createElement('br');

// Student Points - Label
let studentPoints_lbl = document.createElement('LABEL');
studentPoints_lbl.classList.add('label4');
studentPoints_lbl.innerText = 'Student Points';
// Student Points - Field
let studentPoints = document.createElement('input');
studentPoints.id = 'studentPointsEntry';
studentPoints.classList.add('field');
studentPoints.name = 'studentPointsEntry';
studentPoints.type = 'text';
studentPoints.placeholder = 'Enter your Points';

// Empty Row
let EmptyRow4 = document.createElement('br');


// Btn
let addSubmit = document.createElement('button');
addSubmit.classList.add('btnSubmit')
addSubmit.id = 'addSubmit';
addSubmit.innerText = 'Submit';
addSubmit.onclick = studentCreate;


// Appending 
let theContainer = document.getElementById('container');
theContainer.appendChild(headerText); // Appending h1
theContainer.appendChild(studentId_lbl); // Appending Student ID - Label
theContainer.appendChild(studentId); // Appending Student ID - Entry field
theContainer.appendChild(EmptyRow); // Empty Row
theContainer.appendChild(studentName_lbl); // Appending Student Name - Label
theContainer.appendChild(studentName); // Appending Student Name - Entry field
theContainer.appendChild(EmptyRow2); // Empty Row
theContainer.appendChild(studentSurname_lbl); // Appending Student Surname - Label
theContainer.appendChild(studentSurname); // Appending Student Surname - Entry Field
theContainer.appendChild(EmptyRow3); // Empty Row
theContainer.appendChild(studentPoints_lbl); // Appending Student Points - Label
theContainer.appendChild(studentPoints); // Appending Student Points - Entry Field
theContainer.appendChild(EmptyRow4); // Empty Row
theContainer.appendChild(addSubmit); // Form - Submit Button

//--------------//
//    D Code    //
//--------------//

// Constructor function for Student Objects
let students = []; // Global Array Variable for the Objects to check if they exists
let newStudent = [];

function Student(id, name, surname, points) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.points = points;
  this.DidPass = function() {
    if (this.points > 50) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}


// Function to Check if the student exists already
function checkIfStudentExists(studentId) {
  let exists = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < students; i++) {
    if (StudentID == students[i].id) {
      exists = true
    }
  }
  return exists;
}

// Create New Student
function studentCreate() {
  let StudentID = studentId.value;
  let StudentName = studentName.value;
  let StudentSurname = studentSurname.value;
  let StudentPoints = studentPoints.value;

  let exists = checkIfStudentExists(StudentID);
  if (exists) {
    alert('Student exists with the same ID')
  } else {
    let newStudent = new Student(StudentID, StudentName, StudentSurname, StudentPoints);
    students.push(newStudent);
    console.log(students);
    studentId.value = '';
    studentName.value = '';
    studentSurname.value = '';
    studentPoints.value = '';
  }
}

// ------------ //
// Create Table //
// ------------ //

let tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');

for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  var tr = "<tr>";

  /* Verification to add the last decimal 0 */
  if (students[i].value.toString().substring(students[i].value.toString().indexOf('.'), students[i].value.toString().length) < 2)
    students[i].value += "0";

  /* Must not forget the $ sign */
  tr += "<td>" + students[i].key + "</td>" + "<td>$" + students[i].value.toString() + "</td></tr>";

  /* We add the table row to the table body */
  tbody.innerHTML += tr;
}

theContainer.appendChild(tbody);
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <table>
    <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of printing object values into a table:

```js
var object = {
  id: 12345,
  name: "John",
  surname: "Doe",
  points: 60,
  get DidPass() { return this.points > 50 ? true : false} // you have to use a getter, I think
}
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) { //iterate through the object's entries
  let row = tbody.insertRow(-1); // javascript has built-in table functions - insert row to back of table
  let cell1 = row.insertCell(0); //add cells
  let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.textContent = key;
  cell2.textContent = value;
}
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table id="table"><tbody id="tbody"></tbody></table>
```

Comment: This was very helpful, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Add a function to student to render as a row (values as `td`s enclosed by `tr`).  Do the same for the array, enclosing it in `table` and `tbody` tags.

Your code updated below.  See comments `//added this`

```js
//-------------//
// Form Layout //
//-------------//

// h1
let headerText = document.createElement('h1');
headerText.id = 'topH1'
headerText.innerText = 'Please fill the empty fields'

// Student Id - Label
let studentId_lbl = document.createElement('LABEL');
studentId_lbl.classList.add('label1');
studentId_lbl.innerText = 'Student ID';
// Student Id - Field
let studentId = document.createElement('input');
studentId.id = 'studentIdEntry';
studentId.classList.add('field')
studentId.name = 'studentIdEntry';
studentId.type = 'text';
studentId.placeholder = 'Enter your ID ';

let EmptyRow = document.createElement('br');


// Student Name - Label
let studentName_lbl = document.createElement('LABEL');
studentName_lbl.classList.add('label2');
studentName_lbl.innerText = 'Student Name';
// Student Name - Field
let studentName = document.createElement('input');
studentName.id = 'studentNameEntry';
studentName.classList.add('field');
studentName.name = 'studentNameEntry';
studentName.type = 'text';
studentName.placeholder = 'Enter your Name';

// Empty Row
let EmptyRow2 = document.createElement('br');

// Student Surname - Label
let studentSurname_lbl = document.createElement('LABEL');
studentSurname_lbl.classList.add('label3');
studentSurname_lbl.innerText = 'Student Surname';
// Student Surname - Field
let studentSurname = document.createElement('input');
studentSurname.id = 'studentSurnameEntry';
studentSurname.classList.add('field');
studentSurname.name = 'studentSurnameEntry';
studentSurname.type = 'text';
studentSurname.placeholder = 'Enter your Surname';

// Empty Row
let EmptyRow3 = document.createElement('br');

// Student Points - Label
let studentPoints_lbl = document.createElement('LABEL');
studentPoints_lbl.classList.add('label4');
studentPoints_lbl.innerText = 'Student Points';
// Student Points - Field
let studentPoints = document.createElement('input');
studentPoints.id = 'studentPointsEntry';
studentPoints.classList.add('field');
studentPoints.name = 'studentPointsEntry';
studentPoints.type = 'text';
studentPoints.placeholder = 'Enter your Points';

// Empty Row
let EmptyRow4 = document.createElement('br');


// Btn
let addSubmit = document.createElement('button');
addSubmit.classList.add('btnSubmit')
addSubmit.id = 'addSubmit';
addSubmit.innerText = 'Submit';
addSubmit.onclick = studentCreate;


// Appending 
let theContainer = document.getElementById('container');
theContainer.appendChild(headerText); // Appending h1
theContainer.appendChild(studentId_lbl); // Appending Student ID - Label
theContainer.appendChild(studentId); // Appending Student ID - Entry field
theContainer.appendChild(EmptyRow); // Empty Row
theContainer.appendChild(studentName_lbl); // Appending Student Name - Label
theContainer.appendChild(studentName); // Appending Student Name - Entry field
theContainer.appendChild(EmptyRow2); // Empty Row
theContainer.appendChild(studentSurname_lbl); // Appending Student Surname - Label
theContainer.appendChild(studentSurname); // Appending Student Surname - Entry Field
theContainer.appendChild(EmptyRow3); // Empty Row
theContainer.appendChild(studentPoints_lbl); // Appending Student Points - Label
theContainer.appendChild(studentPoints); // Appending Student Points - Entry Field
theContainer.appendChild(EmptyRow4); // Empty Row
theContainer.appendChild(addSubmit); // Form - Submit Button

//--------------//
//    D Code    //
//--------------//

// Constructor function for Student Objects
let students = []; // Global Array Variable for the Objects to check if they exists
let newStudent = [];

function Student(id, name, surname, points) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.points = points;
  this.DidPass = function() {
    if (this.points > 50) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
  this.sortedKeys = function() {
    return Object.keys(this).filter(k => typeof(this[k]) !== 'function').sort();
  };
  // added this
  this.renderAsRow = function() {
    let keys = this.sortedKeys();
    let tds = keys.map(key => `<td>${this[key]}</td>`).join('');
    return `<tr>${tds}</tr>`;
  };
  this.renderAsHeaderRow = function () {
    let keys = this.sortedKeys();
    let tds = keys.map(key => `<th>${key}</th>`).join('');
    return `<tr>${tds}</tr>`;
  };
}


// Function to Check if the student exists already
function checkIfStudentExists(studentId) {
  let exists = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < students; i++) {
    if (StudentID == students[i].id) {
      exists = true
    }
  }
  return exists;
}

// added this
function renderStudentsAsTable(array) {
  if (array.length < 1) return `<table><tbody><tbody></table>`
  let header = array[0].renderAsHeaderRow();
  let rows = array.map(s => s.renderAsRow()).join('');
  return `<table><tbody>${header}${rows}<tbody></table>`;
}


// Create New Student
function studentCreate() {
  let StudentID = studentId.value;
  let StudentName = studentName.value;
  let StudentSurname = studentSurname.value;
  let StudentPoints = studentPoints.value;

  let exists = checkIfStudentExists(StudentID);
  if (exists) {
    alert('Student exists with the same ID')
  } else {
    let newStudent = new Student(StudentID, StudentName, StudentSurname, StudentPoints);
    students.push(newStudent);
    console.log(students);
    // added this
    console.log(renderStudentsAsTable(students))
    studentId.value = '';
    studentName.value = '';
    studentSurname.value = '';
    studentPoints.value = '';
  }
}

// ------------ //
// Create Table //
// ------------ //

let tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');

for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  var tr = "<tr>";

  /* Verification to add the last decimal 0 */
  if (students[i].value.toString().substring(students[i].value.toString().indexOf('.'), students[i].value.toString().length) < 2)
    students[i].value += "0";

  /* Must not forget the $ sign */
  tr += "<td>" + students[i].key + "</td>" + "<td>$" + students[i].value.toString() + "</td></tr>";

  /* We add the table row to the table body */
  tbody.innerHTML += tr;
}

theContainer.appendChild(tbody);
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <table>
    <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```